# Can't create Sharepoint List from imported list template

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-listtemplate

I have a list with some lookup fields. On their list templates, I followed below steps:

- Rename the original .STP to .CAB
- Extract its manifest.xml to a local folder (lets call it {workingfolder})
- Search for the ProductVersion element. This should have a value of 3
  Change its value to 4
- Repackage the manifest.xml into a .CAB. I've done this by using makecab.exe in the      C:\Windows\System32 folder
- Syntax: makecab.exe {workingfolder}\manifest.xml {workingfolder}{template-name}.cab
  Change the generated cabinet's extension from .CAB back to .STP and upload it into the _catalogs/lt

  I uploaded List Template using elements.xml. But I can't even access List Template using code (given below).

  ```
  SPListTemplate listTemplate=null;
      foreach (SPListTemplate template in SPContext.Current.Web.ListTemplates)
      {

          if (template.Name.Equals(templateName))
          {
              listTemplate = template;
          }

      }
      return listTemplate;
  ```

I uploaded the same List Template manually with another name and debugged the code. It returns only the List Template which uploaded manually. I know this is a duplicated question, but no solution is working for me.